# \frac not working as expected in \newcommand

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I'm trying to create some shortcut for the Leibniz notation for partial derivatives. Here the code

```
\newcommand{\px}[1][]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial x}}
```

When I invoke this without arg, it's work properly, but at the time of pass an arg it doesn't work that I expect.

An example of code

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\newcommand{\px}[1][]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial x}}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \px\quad\px{F_x}
    \]
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Instead of

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\px\quad\px[F_x]` should do the trick

Comment: The idea is when I type `\px{F_x}` do the same thing when I type `\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}` and when I type `\px` show `\frac{\partial}{\partial x}`

Comment: optional arguments use `[]` not `{}`

Comment: There are at leasr three interesting packages that greatly simplify typing Leibniz' notation, and do more than this simple shortcut: `esdiff, diffcoeff` and `derivative`. You should take a look at their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define `\px` as

```
\newcommand{\px}[1][]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial x}}
```

the `[1]` defines `\px` as a command with 1 argument, but the `[]` written right after the `[1]` make this argument optional. If you included something between this second pair of square brackets, it would become a default value for this optional argument. So with `\px` defined as above, the command `\px` doesn't take any argument with curly braces, only an optional argument with square brackets.

You could also get the result you are looking for by removing the `[]` in the definition of `\px`. In that case, your command would take a single argument with curly braces.

Here is a complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\px}[1][]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial x}}
\newcommand{\otherpx}[1]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial x}}
\begin{document}
\[
\px{}, \quad \px{F_x}, \quad \px[F_x], \quad
\otherpx{}, \quad \otherpx{F_x}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is a lot useful

Comment: Very kind Vincent I hope that you I have seen my comment of the professor who didn't even ask me thanks since he had the MikTeX distribution a bit outdated.

Answer (score 4):

Is this the required result of the your question?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\newcommand{\px}[1][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial x}}
\begin{document}
    \[
    \px[F_x], \px
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's works

Comment: @Patrick Happy to help you... it's true I'm scarce user compared to the others but sometimes I find the right solution.

Comment: Why the second argument?

Comment: @egreg Done!!!! Before I was in chat on Physics.SE.